# "Unable to resolve entity" error when trying to transact a Datomic schema

Tags: clojure, datomic

I am a Datomic super-newbie. I'm trying to add a taxonomy to my database, but am getting an error that I can't follow. The error is:

```
{:datomic.client-spi/request-id "c587b3e8-8f19-45f5-a563-bdba13e3a0d8",
 :cognitect.anomalies/category :cognitect.anomalies/not-found,
 :cognitect.anomalies/message
 ":db.error/not-an-entity Unable to resolve entity: {:idx -1000000, :part :db.part/db} in datom [{:idx -1000000, :part :db.part/db} :db/ident :arb/title]",
 :dbs
 [{:database-id "datomic:dev://localhost:4334/datemo",
   :t 1004,
   :next-t 1009,
   :history false}]}
```

Here is the taxonomy that I'm using:

```
[{:db/id #db/id [:db.part/db]
  :db/ident         :arb/title
  :db/unique        :db.unique/identity
  :db/valueType     :db.type/string
  :db/cardinality   :db.cardinality/one
  :db/fulltext      true
  :db/index         true
  :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}

 {:db/id #db/id [:db.part/db]
  :db/ident         :arb/description
  :db/unique        :db.unique/identity
  :db/valueType     :db.type/string
  :db/cardinality   :db.cardinality/one
  :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}

 {:db/id #db/id [:db.part/db]
  :db/ident         :arb/content
  :db/unique        :db.unique/identity
  :db/valueType     :db.type/ref
  :db/isComponent   true
  :db/cardinality   :db.cardinality/many
  :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db}]
```

And here is the call that I made:

```
(def arb-tx (-> (io/resource "schemas/arb.edn") ;; the schema above
                (read-all)
                (first)))

(pprint (<!! (client/transact conn {:tx-data arb-tx})))
```

It's hard for me to understand from the error message what exactly is not resolvable here. I think my understanding of what is going on underneath the hood is too vague to understand what is wrong here. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Datomic Client library doesn't support explicit partition or :db.install/_attribute in schema definition. Those elements were required when using Peers prior to Datomic 0.9.5430.

Try replacing your schema definition with:

```
[{:db/ident         :arb/title
  :db/unique        :db.unique/identity
  :db/valueType     :db.type/string
  :db/cardinality   :db.cardinality/one
  :db/fulltext      true
  :db/index         true}

 {:db/ident         :arb/description
  :db/unique        :db.unique/identity
  :db/valueType     :db.type/string
  :db/cardinality   :db.cardinality/one}

 {:db/ident         :arb/content
  :db/unique        :db.unique/identity
  :db/valueType     :db.type/ref
  :db/isComponent   true
  :db/cardinality   :db.cardinality/many}]
```

-Marshall